# How can I test for the index that a letter is in in a string, and use this to replace parts of another string?

Tags: string, python-3.x, replace

So I would have the user enter a letter, then I can also test to see if the letter is in a certain word. However, what I aim to do is to obtain the index of the letter in the word, e.g. if the user enters 'e' and my word is 'great' then it would output '2'. Additionally, I want to use this information to replace parts of another string with the same indexes as the letter. Like hangman, so if the output is '2' then say I have another string, 'balloon' or '******', I want to replace the first 'l' or the according '*' (2nd index) with 'e'.

Comment: Well strings are just arrays of characters, so just use the `index()` method.

Comment: @"Bob The Berserking Bear"  If you could add some code snippets of what you have tried and some sample inputs and outputs It would help us know exactly what you are trying to achieve. Reading the question I'm not sure if there are 2,3 or 4 strings being manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Python Strings are immutable, so we need to work with them as lists

```
>>> string1 = "great"
>>> string2 = "balloon"
>>> char = "e"
>>> string2 = list(string2)
>>> string2[string1.index(char)] = char
>>> string2
['b', 'a', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'n']
>>> string2 = ''.join(string2)
'baeloon'
```